# Combine certain rows values of duplicate rows Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe based on football players. I am finding duplicate rows for when a player has transferred mid-season. My aim is to add the points the accumalted in both leagues and add them together to make just one row.

Here is a sample of the data:

```
name    full_name   club    Points  Start   Sub
84  S. Mustafi  Shkodran Mustafi    Arsenal 76  26  1
85  S. Mustafi  Shkodran Mustafi    Arsenal -2  0   1
89  Bruno   Bruno Soriano Llido Villarreal CF   43  15  16
90  Bruno   Bruno Gonzalez Cabrera  Getafe CF   43  15  16
119 Oscar   Oscar dos Santos Emboaba    NaN 16  5   8
120 Oscar   Oscar dos Santos Emboaba    NaN 1   0   2
121 Oscar   Oscar Rodriguez Arnaiz  Real Madrid CF  16  5   8
122 Oscar   Oscar Rodriguez Arnaiz  Real Madrid CF  1   0   2
188 C. Bravo    Claudio Bravo   Manchester City 61  22  8
189 C. Bravo    Claudio Bravo   Manchester City 1   1   0
193 Naldo   Ronaldo Aparecido Rodrigues FC Schalke 04   58  19  1
194 Naldo   Edinaldo Gomes Pereira  RCD Espanyol    58  19  1
200 G. Castro   Gonzalo Castro  Borussia Dortmund   79  23  6
201 G. Castro   Gonzalo Castro  Malaga CF   79  23  6
209 Juanfran    Juan Francisco Torres Belen Atletico Madrid 86  21  8
210 Juanfran    Juan Francisco Torres Belen Atletico Madrid 74  34  2
211 Juanfran    Juan Francisco Moreno Fuertes   RC Coruna   86  21  8
212 Juanfran    Juan Francisco Moreno Fuertes   RC Coruna   74  34  2
```

My goal dataframe would have players like for example Mustafi's Points Start and Sum values added together to give just one player.
Players like Bruno are clearly not the same person so I don't want to add the two brunos together.

```
name    full_name   club    Points  Start   Sub
84  S. Mustafi  Shkodran Mustafi    Arsenal 74  26  2
89  Bruno   Bruno Soriano Llido Villarreal CF   43  15  16
90  Bruno   Bruno Gonzalez Cabrera  Getafe CF   43  15  16
119 Oscar   Oscar dos Santos Emboaba    NaN 17  5   10
121 Oscar   Oscar Rodriguez Arnaiz  Real Madrid CF  17  5   10
188 C. Bravo    Claudio Bravo   Manchester City 62  23  8
193 Naldo   Ronaldo Aparecido Rodrigues FC Schalke 04   58  19  1
194 Naldo   Edinaldo Gomes Pereira  RCD Espanyol    58  19  1
200 G. Castro   Gonzalo Castro  Borussia Dortmund   158 46  12
209 Juanfran    Juan Francisco Torres Belen Atletico Madrid 86  21  8
212 Juanfran    Juan Francisco Moreno Fuertes   RC Coruna   74  34  2
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need:

```
df[['name','full_name','club']] = df[['name','full_name','club']].fillna('')
d = {'Points':'sum', 'Start':'sum', 'Sub':'sum', 'club':'first'}
df = (df.groupby(['name','full_name'], sort=False, as_index=False)
        .agg(d)
        .reindex(columns=df.columns))

with pd.option_context('display.expand_frame_repr', False):
    print (df)
           name                      full_name                   club  Points  Start  Sub
0    S. Mustafi               Shkodran Mustafi                Arsenal      74     26    2
1   Bruno Bruno                   SorianoLlido          Villarreal CF      43     15   16
2   Bruno Bruno               Gonzalez Cabrera              Getafe CF      43     15   16
3         Oscar       Oscar dos Santos Emboaba                             17      5   10
4         Oscar         Oscar Rodriguez Arnaiz         Real Madrid CF      17      5   10
5      C. Bravo                  Claudio Bravo        Manchester City      62     23    8
6         Naldo    Ronaldo Aparecido Rodrigues          FC Schalke 04      58     19    1
7         Naldo         Edinaldo Gomes Pereira           RCD Espanyol      58     19    1
8     G. Castro                 Gonzalo Castro      Borussia Dortmund     158     46   12
9      Juanfran          Juan Francisco Torres  Belen Atletico Madrid     160     55   10
10     Juanfran  Juan Francisco Moreno Fuertes              RC Coruna     160     55   10
```

**Explanation**:

1. First replace `NaNs` to `''` by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) for avoid omit rows with them in `groupby`
2. Aggregate by [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with `dictionary` with specify columns and their aggregating functions
3. Last for display all rows together temporarly use [`with`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#getting-and-setting-options)